# Examples of compact complex manifolds $M$ with $c_1(M) < 0, = 0, > 0$

Tags: complex-geometry

In the context of Kähler-Einstein metrics, I am looking for a bunch of explicit examples of compact complex manifolds $M$ with $c_1(M) < 0, = 0, > 0$ so that I can do some explicit calculations with them. I am aware of very few examples like case of curves (i.e. Riemann surface), projective space and hypersurfaces in projective space. I am especially interested in examples of manifolds whose canonical bundle is big and nef but not ample.

Comment: An hypersurface $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ of degree $d$ satisfies $K_X\sim \mathcal O_X(d-n-1)$. Therefore, $c_1(X)<0$ iff $d>n+1$ (and similarly for other signs). 
As for finding varieties with $K_X$ big and nef but not ample, you can look at that paper for instance: 
http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178224978

Comment: You can take a surface of degree $>4$ in $\mathbb CP^3$ having ordinary double points and blow these points up. The canonical bundle of the blow up is big and semi-ample

Comment: @aglearner - how to prove this?

Comment: @Bingo, the point is that the canonical bundle of the blow up is the pullback of the canonical bundle of the surface that we blow up. (this is because we blow up double points, i.e. we have what is called "a crepant resolution"). On the other hand, that canonical bundle on the singular surface is just $O(d-4)$, where $d$ is the degree of the surface. This is clearly ample. It follows that the canonical bundle on the blow up is both semiample and big (as a pull back of an ample line bundle).

Comment: Compact Hermitian symmetric spaces have $c_1>0$, and are nice to calculate with; see Mok's book *Metric Rigidity Theorems on Hermitian Locally Symmetric Manifolds*, and the wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_symmetric_space and Helgason's book *Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces*.